# JSF Live search with primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to implement live searching with primefaces inputtext, all works well until the situation where user deletes last symbol in search field and all results must be shown back. For example when i open page all results are shown, i type letter a, results being filtered, delete a and again see all results. Problem is, when i delete last letter the ajax event is not being fired (maybe because of empty string?). Code for inputtext:

```
<p:inputText id="searchString" title="searchString" value="#{findDoctorBean.searchString}" >
    <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{findDoctorBean.searchForDoctorsByName}" process="@this" update=":resultGroup"></p:ajax>
</p:inputText>
```

How should i fire an event in such situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i tested your Code with the following Ajax listenerMethod:

```
    public final void search(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
        System.out.println("search: "+this.searchString);
    }
```

and its being fired also with empty Strings. 
So your Problem is in your `searchForDoctorsByName` Method in your bean, you have to reset (reInit) your DB-Items List if entered String is emtpy. So your Problem is in your SQL statement not in ajax.

Comment: Thank you. I guess problem was in that i wasn't using AjaxBehaviorEvent.